# Error when running JAR created by Maven Assembly plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven-assembly-plugin

I am working on Eclipse/Spring/Maven project. My pom.xml looks like this:

> ```
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <groupId>com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise</groupId>
>   <artifactId>springexample</artifactId>
>   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
>     <packaging>jar</packaging>
>
>     <build>
>     <plugins>
>      <plugin>
>                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
>                 <version>2.2.1</version>
>                 <executions>
>                     <execution>
>                         <id>package-jar-with-dependencies</id>
>                         <phase>package</phase>
>                         <goals>
>                             <goal>single</goal>
>                         </goals>
>                         <configuration>
>                             <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
>                             <descriptorRefs>
>                                 <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
>                             </descriptorRefs>
>                             <archive>
>                                 <manifest>
>                                     <mainClass>com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.App2</mainClass>
>                                 </manifest>
>                             </archive>
>                             <resources>
>                                   <resource>
>                               <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
>                               <filtering>true</filtering>
>                                   </resource>
>                           </resources>
>                         </configuration>
>                     </execution>
>                 </executions>
>             </plugin>
> </plugins>
>
>
>               </build>        
>           <dependencies>
>               <dependency>
>                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>                   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
>               <version> 3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
>               </dependency>
>               <dependency>
>                   <groupId>com.rapplogic</groupId>
>                   <artifactId>xbee-api</artifactId>
>                   <version> 0.9</version>
>               </dependency>
>               <dependency>
>                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>                   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
>                   <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
>               </dependency>
>
>               <dependency>
>                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>                   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
>                   <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
>               </dependency>
>               <dependency>
>                   <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
>           <version>1.2.2</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
>           <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
>           <version>1.0</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>           <version>5.1.6</version>
>       </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>jfreechart</groupId>
>             <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
>             <version>1.0.0</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>jcommon</groupId>
>             <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
>             <version>0.9.5</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.graphstream</groupId>
>             <artifactId>gs-core</artifactId>
>             <version>1.2</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.graphstream</groupId>
>             <artifactId>gs-ui</artifactId>
>             <version>1.2</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.graphstream</groupId>
>             <artifactId>gs-algo</artifactId>
>             <version>1.2</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>           <groupId>log4j</groupId>
>           <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
>           <version>1.2.17</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
>           <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
>       </dependency>           
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.rxtx</groupId>
>           <artifactId>rxtx</artifactId>
>           <version>2.1.7</version>
>       </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.bidib.jbidib.org.qbang.rxtx</groupId>
>             <artifactId>rxtxcomm</artifactId>
>             <version>2.2</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
>         <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
>       </dependency>
>     </dependencies>
> </project>
> ```

My applicationContext.xml looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd"> 
.
.
.
```

I do  `mvn install` and then `mvn package`. I get the output as `springexample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` in the target directory of the project. Then I type the command `java - jar springexample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Config
uration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespa
ce [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
```

Browsinf through similar problems over Internet, I found two possible sources of the error:

1. Non-specifying the spring library for namespace handling (spring-tx) - done (included in dependencies)
   2.Non-specifying applicationContext.xml in the resources of the maven assembly plugin - done (resources tag included in the plugin configuration).

After that, I do not know what could be the problem. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.. Could you solve this? @MichalB

Answer (score 0):

try adding this, instead of 4.0.0.RELEASE:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version> 3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and then do a `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 0):

I just faced almost the same issue (the app worked using my IDE but not using the generated jar file). I solved it by adding the option `<Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>`. This option specifies that your Uber java may contain various Java versions of Java files.

```
<archive>
  <manifestEntries>
    <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
  </manifestEntries>
  <manifest>
    <mainClass>com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.App2</mainClass>
  </manifest>
</archive>
```

See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/multirelease.html for more details.